# Selecting specific subnet id from virtual network with multiple subnets

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I want to reference the id of `subnet 2` in another resource block but the subnets don't have an index value. i.e "${azurerm_virtual_network.test.subnet.2.id}" will not work.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "test" {
  name                = "virtualNetwork1"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  dns_servers         = ["10.0.0.4", "10.0.0.5"]

  subnet {
    name           = "subnet1"
    address_prefix = "10.0.1.0/24"
  }

  subnet {
    name           = "subnet2"
    address_prefix = "10.0.2.0/24"
  }

  subnet {
    name           = "subnet3"
    address_prefix = "10.0.3.0/24"
    security_group = "${azurerm_network_security_group.test.id}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Solved with the help of [Expose ID of an embedded subnet defined in azurerm_virtual_network #1913](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/1913)

```
...
subnet_id = "${azurerm_virtual_network.test.subnet.*.id[1]}"
...
```

Comment: It works but can you please explain the "*" semantics

Answer (score 2):

`azurerm_virtual_network.test.subnet.*.id[1]`

What has happened here is that `*` gets all subnets and `[1]` is pointing to index 2.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use: `tolist(azurerm_virtual_network.test.subnet)[1].id`